# DiskInternals Linux Recovery: building file tree

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I am running Windows 7x 64. My Seagate 1TB NAS stopped working, so I removed the HD and attached it, using a USB/SATA adapter, to a USB port on the computer, and ran DiskInternals Linux Recovery (x64), which identified the partitions, and said the drive was damaged but recoverable.

After about 8 hours of processing, DI has moved on to the "Building file tree" phase, but there's no progressbar or other UI indication that it's still working.

I've never used the DiskInternals software before. Will the "Building file tree" phase also take ~8 hours?

In Task Manager it shows as using 25% of the system CPU and exactly the same amount of RAM (1,323,352K), for the past hour now.

Answer (score 0):

It just took another 45 minutes, so it hadn't gotten hung up.